# correctly delete record from Kafka ktable

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I want to correctly delete object from KTable.

I have following stream processing data:

```
input
.map(this::deserialize)
.filter(((key, event) ->
    Arrays.asList(
        "AssessmentInitialized",
        "AssessmentRenamed",
        "AssessmentDeleted"
    ).contains(event.eventType())))
.map( ... do mapping  ... )
.groupBy((key, event) -> key, Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), domainEventSerde))
.aggregate(
    Assessment::new,
    (key, event, assessment) -> assessment.handleEvent(event),
    Materialized.<String, Assessment, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(ASSESSMENTS_STORE)
        .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
        .withValueSerde(assessmentSerde)
);
```

and `assessment.handleEvent(event)` returns `null` when it processes `AssessmentDeleted` event. Serde is `this.assessmentSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Assessment.class, objectMapper);` where mapper is default com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper bean.

After I event is processed by this stream I see in Kafka KTable changelog following value:

```
{
"topic": "events-consumer-v1-assessments-store-changelog",
"key": "5d6d7a70-c907-460f-ac88-69705f079939",
"value": "ée",
"partition": 0,
"offset": 2
}
```

And it doesn't look like something I want to have. Is that way of deleting object correct? I expected that if I push null as value to aggregate operation it will be removed, but looks like some trash left and I'm not sure if its mapper problem or incorrect way of deletion or correct KTable behavior.

Comment: How do you check `Kafka KTable changelog`?

Comment: I'm using landoop Kafka ui docker image `docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -e "KAFKA_REST_PROXY_URL=http://$(ifconfig en0 | awk '/inet / {print $2}'):8082" -e "PROXY=true" landoop/kafka-topics-ui` with it I can see in related changelog topic.

Comment: Ok tested also like this: `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic events-consumer-v1-assessments-store-changelog --from-beginning                                                                                          
{"uuid":"a688b338-6e20-4574-891c-88216788bff5","name":"New Assessment", ..... }
null` Looks like correct? Order of events was `SomeEvent1`, `AssessmentDeleted `.

Comment: yes It looks ok, but I think you have to fix your program, because NullPointerException, will be thrown if some event after `AssessmentDeleted` will be for the same key.

Comment: Any proposed solutions? I know how to handle it on event's (business) level but that would be nice to handle it on Kafka (infrastructure) level. Lets say that Kafka checks that it has object with this key but null as value? Anyway can you please write response that it looks like checking error? That was my main confusion that this landoop thing displayed null as weird json.

Comment: Question is, what would you like to achieve?, Is that aggregation needed? maybe just map to null and than `Materialized`?

Comment: For more complex stateful operations is better to use Processor API.

Comment: Ok, I'll investigate more on this. Thank you for amazing help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case it seems, that an issue was in a checking tool. Because of some reason it deserialize `null` value not properly.
Always it good to use Kafka tools to check it first (`kafka-console-consumer.sh`, `kafka-console-producer.sh`).